# Why does the filepath become invalid when in reality it is completely valid?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, path, filepath

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

filepath = "G:\learning python\page view time series\trum.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col = "date", parse_dates=True)
```

The above code gives the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'G:\\learning python\\page view time series\trum.csv'
```

But if I change the name of my csv file to 'laem.csv' and update the path, then the code runs perfectly.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

filepath = "G:\learning python\page view time series\laem.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, index_col = "date", parse_dates=True)
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: lets read it raw. `filepath =r"G:\learning python\page view time series\laem.csv"`

Comment: @wwnda.  Nice catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `\t` actually means "put a tab space here", not litteraly `\` and `t`.
You can see this by trying

```
print("Hello\tWorld") # "Hello   World"
```

You can avoid this by either escaping the backslash itself with `\\`

```
print("Hello\\tWorld") # "Hello\tWorld"
```

or using a raw string by prepending an `r` to the string literal.

```
print(r"Hello\tWorld") # "Hello\tWorld"
```

You can read about string literals [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).

Answer (score 1):

Python interprets `\t` in a string as an escape code for a tab character. However, `\l` has no such special interpretation so it gets interpreted as a backslash plus `l`.

To fix this, I suggest using raw strings, i.e. prefix the string with an `r`:

```
filepath = r"G:\learning python\page view time series\trum.csv"
```

Alternatively, you could escape the backslashes, but that gets a bit tedious:

```
filepath = "G:\\learning python\\page view time series\\trum.csv"
```

Strictly speaking, the only one you really need to escape in this case is the one before `t`, but it's probably more trouble than it's worth (and also possibly confusing) to escape some backslashes but not others.